# Dropdown that has an option to input a field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to include in the option, that if the user chooses/clicks the `Other please specify` option, he gets an option to give input. The characters thus input will instantly show relevant nationalities in a dropdown bar.
For a javascript function based solution for this, how can I make a call to that function in my html code or in dropdown. Thanks! :D

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label for="status" class="control-label col-xs-4">
    <p class="left">Nationality</p>
</label>

<select name="status" required>
    <option></option>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Filipino</option>
    <option value='Filipino'>Filipino</option>
    <option value='American'>American</option>
    <option value='Japanese'>Japanese</option>
    <option value='French'>French</option>
    <option value='Sweden'>Sweden</option>
    <option value='other'>Others please specify.</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot to share your JavaScript...

Comment: there is still no javascript involved in my dropdown code, I'm guessing that javascript function was a viable solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below code

```js
var code = $('#code'); //input field
code.hide(); //initially hide

$("#status").on('change', function() {
  var selected_option = $('#status option:selected').eq(0);
  if (selected_option.val() == 'other') {
    code.show();
    code.val(''); //empty the field every-time selecting the option
    console.log(selected_option.val());
  } else {
    code.hide();
  }
  console.log(selected_option.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="status" class="control-label col-xs-4">
    <p class="left">Nationality</p>
  </label>

  <select name="status" id="status" required>
    <option></option>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Filipino</option>
    <option value='Filipino'>Filipino</option>
    <option value='American'>American</option>
    <option value='Japanese'>Japanese</option>
    <option value='French'>French</option>
    <option value='Sweden'>Sweden</option>
    <option value='other'>Others please specify.</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" name="code" id="code" />
</div>
```

**Below is the full implementation**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Nationality</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="status" class="control-label col-xs-4">
    <p class="left">Nationality</p>
    </label>
    <select name="status" id="status" required="required">
        <option></option>
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Filipino</option>
        <option value='Filipino'>Filipino</option>
        <option value='American'>American</option>
        <option value='Japanese'>Japanese</option>
        <option value='French'>French</option>
        <option value='Sweden'>Sweden</option>
        <option value='other'>Others please specify.</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="code" id="code">
</div>
<script>
var code = $('#code'); //input field
code.hide(); //initially hide

$("#status").on('change', function() {
  var selected_option = $('#status option:selected').eq(0);
  if (selected_option.val() == 'other') {
    code.show();
    code.val(''); //empty the field every-time selecting the option
    console.log(selected_option.val());
  } else {
    code.hide();
  }
  console.log(selected_option.val());
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Vista you need to insert in inside the `<script></script>` tag below your html code.make sure to add **jquery**

Comment: It doesn't work when I tried it with my browser :(. It works when I "Run code snippet"

Comment: @Vista tell me the way you include this above script

Comment: <script>jquery</script> then html codes after that <script>function<script>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> You need to have a `listener` for your `select` and take the action as per the selected value..

```js
var inputLabel = $('#inputLabel');
var onOptionChange = function() {
  if (this.value == 'other') {
    inputLabel.fadeIn(100);
  } else {
    inputLabel.fadeOut(100);
  }
};
$('#status').on('change', onOptionChange);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="status" class="control-label col-xs-4">Nationality</label>
  <select name="status" id="status" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your Nationality</option>
    <option value='Filipino'>Filipino</option>
    <option value='American'>American</option>
    <option value='Japanese'>Japanese</option>
    <option value='French'>French</option>
    <option value='Sweden'>Sweden</option>
    <option value='other'>Others please specify.</option>
  </select>
  <label for="input" id="inputLabel" style="display: none">Other:
    <input type="text" id="input">
  </label>
</div>
```